# How do I get rid of the nav menu margin in Bootstrap/Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get rid of the left and right spacing seen here between the colors:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heaml.png)

I am trying to create a custom theme on Wordpress with Bootstrap.

I have tried to remove padding, which just makes the colored `li` smaller and the `a` pushed to the edges.

I also tried removing margin, but that didn't get me anywhere.

Here is the relevant `Header.php` content:

```
<div class="blog-masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="blog-nav">
      <?php $directoryURI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; $path = parse_url($directoryURI, PHP_URL_PATH); $components = explode('/', $path); $part = $components[2]; ?>
      <a class="blog-nav-item <?php if ($part=="") {echo 'current_page_item'; } else  {echo '';}?>" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'wpurl' );?>">HOME</a>
      <?php wp_list_pages( '&title_li=' ); echo $_GET['pg']; ?>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Best regards,

Comment: Do you have a link to you website? It's probably something simple, but I can't diagnose the issue without looking at the CSS+HTML. Have you tried changing margin, rather than padding?

Comment: Hi Kellen! Here is the link: http://whatloop.com

Comment: @BrydonMcCluskey where is the menu?? I don't see it in your site

Comment: ^ I second Daniel's question. @BrydonMcCluskey

Comment: Sorry everyone! Was on my phone and not paying full attention. Here it is: http://whatloop.com/wpTheme @DanielH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li.page_item, .blog-nav-item {
    margin: 0 -2px 0 -2px;
}
```

try this, should fix it. Most of the time bootstrap will set a 15px margin to left and right, you need to use !important to overwrite it (bad practice).

But seems like there is a 2px (left and right) margin between your li.page_item